# A different characterization of the infimum of a set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $E$ be a set that is bounded below. Let $l$ be a lower bound of $E$. Show that $ l = \inf E $ iff given any $\epsilon > 0$ we can always find $z \in E$ with $z < l + \epsilon $.

## Attempt

Let $\epsilon > 0 $ be given. Assume $l = \inf E $. By definition, $l + \epsilon $ cannot be a lower bound of $E$. Hence, we can choose some $z \in E$ with $z < l + \epsilon $

Conversely, say $l$ is a lower bound of $E$. To arrive at our conclusion, we must show that $\mathbf{no}$ $k$ with $k > l $ can be a lower bound of $E$. Suppose there is some $k$ with the mentioned property and choose $\epsilon = k - l > 0$. By hypothesis, we can find $z \in E$ with $z < l + \epsilon = k $ which means that $k$ cannot be a lower bound.

Is my solution correct? thanks.

Comment: Sounds good except the last sentence should be $k$ cannot be a lower bound.