# Sequence limits using epsilon

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I just wanted to find out a few examples of how to use the epsilon characterisation to for limits. One example should help me get my head around these and do other questions.

$A_n=2/(n^2+\sqrt{3})$ prove using epsilon characterisation that $A_n$ has limit $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED WITH MORE DETAILS**

> **Definition**. We say that a sequence of numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots$ converges to a number $a$ if for each $\varepsilon>0$ you can find an $n_0\in\mathbf N$ such that for every $n\geq n_0$ it holds:
>
> $$|a_n-a|<\varepsilon.$$

In other words, the sequence converges to $a$ if eventually the terms are "as close as you want" to $a$.

In your example you have to show that for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $n_0\in\mathbf N$ such that if $n\geq n_0$ then $|A_n-0|<\varepsilon$ (because $A_n$ converges to zero.)

We now note that

$$|A_n|=\frac{2}{n^2+\sqrt{3}}\leq\frac 2{n^2}.$$

We do that because it is simpler to work with $\frac 2{n^2}$. Now, since for any $n\geq n_0$ it holds that

$$\frac2{n^2}\leq\frac2{n_0^2},$$

we bound $|A_n|$ ($n\geq n_0$) as follows:

$$|A_n|\leq\frac2{n^2}\leq\frac2{n_0^2}.$$

Now suppose that $\frac2{n_0^2}<\varepsilon$. In that case, we would obtain that

$$|A_n|\leq\frac2{n^2}\leq\frac2{n_0^2}<\varepsilon,$$

and that is exactly what we want! But, do the condition $\frac2{n_0^2}<\varepsilon$ ever holds? Yes, but only if $n_0>\sqrt{\varepsilon/2}$. But there is no problem, since we are free to choose the $n_0$. So let $n_0>\sqrt{\varepsilon/2}$ (for example, $n_0=[\sqrt{\varepsilon/2}]+1$, where $[\cdot]$ is the floor function.) Then

$$|A_n|\leq\frac2{n^2}\leq\frac2{n_0^2}<\frac{2}{(\sqrt{\varepsilon/2})^2}=\varepsilon.$$

By our definition, this proves that $A_n$ converges to $0$.

Now we consider your other example, $B_n=\sqrt{5}+\frac{2}{n^2+\sqrt{3}}$. We will show that $B_n$ converges to $\sqrt{5}$. Read again the definition. What we have to do? To study the difference $|B_n-\sqrt{5}|$. Let's do it:

$$|B_n-\sqrt{5}|=\left|\sqrt{5}+\frac{2}{n^2+\sqrt{3}}-\sqrt{5}\right|=
\left|\frac{2}{n^2+\sqrt{3}}\right|.$$

The term $\sqrt{5}$ has disappeared! So if we want to prove that $B_n$ tends to $\sqrt{5}$, we only have to find $n_0$ such that $|\frac{2}{n^2+\sqrt{3}}|<\varepsilon$. Is it possible? Indeed, we have just done it above.

Comment: hey thanks is there a youtube video or a title for proofs like these that I can watch? what if I made it sqrt(5)+2/(n^2+sqrt(3))

Comment: I don't know youtube videos, but you can find this in any analysis book. To cite two examples: *Calculus* by Tom Apostol and *Introduction to Real Analysis* by Bartle and Sherbert. Concerning $\sqrt{5}+2/(n^2+\sqrt{3})$, the proof is exactly as the one of the post, but now it converges to $\sqrt{5}$. Just calculate $|A_n-\sqrt{5}|$.

Comment: Thanks for the help I wrote |An - sqrt(5))|=2/(n^2+sqrt(3))≤2/n^2  I don't know where to go after that I don't really understand how you go or what you did with the n0 and sqrt(e/2) stuff

Comment: Now take the same $n_0$ as in the post, and you are done!

Comment: Ok I'll try to add more details

Comment: thanks if you do. I tried |An-sqrt(5))|<ε   if 2/n^2 is smaller than ε |An-sqrt(5))|<ε  (2/ε^2)<n  N>2/ε^2   n≥N>(2/ε^2) -> 2/(n^2)<ε    |An-sqrt(5))|<2/n^2 <ε    I tried this I'm not sure if its right I followed my notes but I don't understand it

Comment: I've expanded the post. If something is not clear, tell me.

Comment: Thank you so much man I tried a different example hoping you could check it (n^2+n+1)/(2n^2+1)  An=1/2  |An-0.5|=(2n+1)/(2(2n^2+1))      (2n+1)/(2(2n^2+1))≤(2n+n)/2(2n^2)<3/4n   we write (3/4n)≤3/4n0  then |An-0.5|≤(3/4n)<(3/4n0)<epsilon  Only holds for no>3/4e  so, |An-0.5|≤(3/4n)<(3/4no)<(3/4(0.75epsilon))=epsilon   Apart from the missed lines like definitions and improving the layout is that correct? I appreciate your help its helped a lot

Comment: Indeed, your solution is right, well done!

Comment: You're a life saver thanks so much so the one with the sort(5) is the exact same as your first post just writing |An-sqrt(5))| in replacement

Comment: Yes, that's it. By the way, if the answer was useful you may want to "accept" it (clicking in the check mark at the left of the post.)

Comment: Sorry I didn't know to accept. Hey I'm assuming you know a lot about analysis what does  Write down explicitly the ε-characterisation of β = infirm Y look like. I know a bit on supremums and infimums but not how to write that down

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043357/a-different-characterization-of-the-infimum-of-a-set.